# Howto parse multiple arguments that are in mixed order

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

Title may be a little confusing, sorry. In python 2.7, this is what I want to do but not sure how. When running a script, I have 3 arguments. 2 boards, 1 port. One of the boards will be a receiver and the other a transmitter.

./test.py -board1 A -board2 B -port 3 ..here board2 with argument B is receiver.

./test.py -board2 B -board1 A -port 3 ..here board1 with argument A is receiver.

Is it possible to parse arguments in this specific format to get what I want?

Comment: The `args` attributes will be the same in both cases.  `args.board1` will be `A`, regardless of the order.

Comment: Correct. Maybe I should have been more clear. Whichever is in the second position will be the receiver, but I need to know if it's from board1 or board2.

Comment: What's the significance of `-board1` label?  You can't, with `argparse`, both flag as string with a name like that, and at the same time make use of the order.  There are `positional` arguments, but you can't use the two kinds together.

Comment: If `argparse` doesn't give you as much information as you'd like, you can always parse `sys.argv` yourself.  It's just a list a strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `board1` and `board2` required flags with an `argparse` parser. I would recommend giving the arguments more meaningful names, such as `receiver` and `transmitter`.

```py
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

>>> parser.add_argument("-r", "--receiver", required=True)
>>> parser.add_argument("-t", "--transmitter", required=True)
>>> parser.add_argument("-p", "--port", type=int, default=1234)

>>> result = parser.parse_args(["--receiver", "A", "-t", "B", "--port", "1010"])
>>> result.receiver
'A'
>>> result.transmitter
'B'
>>> result.port
1010

>>> result = parser.parse_args(["--transmitter", "X", "-r", "Y"])
>>> result.receiver
'Y'
>>> result.transmitter
'X'
>>> result.port  # the default
1234
```